# Unable to send email from Einstein chatbot

Tags: email, einstein, chat

The cloud integration user which is a default user created for the Einstein Chatbot is not able to send e mail.The records are being created but email is not received at the receiver.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Try adding another address to the recipients list, maybe a hotmail address, you'll see that it is received (most lively in the junk). If so, investigated why the recipients email server is blocking it.

Comment: I tried sending to other adresses. It didn't work. Were you sending the email from BOT?

Comment: Yes. The problem looked exactly like yours. The send email apex call returned success and there's a record in EmailMessage. It turned up my hotmail (junk) from cloud@...